# Is the name of "Pomino" reminiscent of "Omino"?

Tags: word-usage

Gerolamo Pomino Jr. is a character in Luigi Pirandello's *Il fu Mattia Pascal*. I wonder whether the name *Pomino* would readily make one recall the word *[Omino](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/omino#Italian)*. I think it might, because this man has a very petty character, by the novel. But I am not sure, because associations like this are a very tricky matter, you think it should work and yet it doesn't in another language, or it might be not as obvious as you suppose. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than the particular word *omino* what the name suggests is the suffix *-ino*:

> **-ino¹**  (f. *-ina*). – Alterating and derivating suffix, of various origins (some uses were already present in Latin), employed with various functions: 1. With alterative value, it forms the [diminutive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutive) of nouns, like *nipotino*, *visino*, *gattino*, *paesino*, etc. and of adjectives like *grandino*, *bruttino*, *leggerino*, etc.
>   *(From the [Vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ino1/))*

So the name gives a faint impression of "smallness". However I don't want to overemphasize the effect: it is not particularly strong and the suffix *-ino* is relatively common in Italian last names (including, in a regional variant, my own! :))